# Restoring system property ("os.name")

Tags: java, system-properties

So while coding I accidentaly clicked on "clearProperty" instead of "getProperty"...
I've cleared "os.name" and now I'm getting null every time I try to read it. How can I restore it to generic state? If I can't do it automatically, how should I know the exact string my windows has?

Edit:

In Eclipse when you type "System." you have set of all available methods. I clicked clear instead of get and launcher program.

P.S - I know it sounds impossible, but still...

Comment: Clicked on it where? What do you mean?

Comment: @Radiodef probably the IDE drop-down quick selection menus.

Comment: Exacly, but again: anyone knows how to reset it or what is a string for Windows 7 Ultimate x64?

Answer (score 3):

Just restart the JVM that is having the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `clearProperty` only removes the entry from a Hashtable. If you don't want to clear the property, remove the line that calls it and run the program again.

[System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

> These changes are not persistent.